# setText crashes the app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app which has a counter which increases every time onStart function is implimented

```
package com.example.android.lifecycle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.lifecycle.util.StatusTracker;
import com.example.android.lifecycle.util.Utils;

import static com.example.android.lifecycle.R.layout.activity_a;

public class ActivityA extends Activity{

private String mActivityName;
private TextView mStatusView;
private TextView mStatusAllView;
private StatusTracker mStatusTracker = StatusTracker.getInstance();
int count = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_a);

    mActivityName = getString(R.string.activity_a);
    mStatusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_view_a);
    mStatusAllView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_view_all_a);

    mStatusTracker.setStatus(mActivityName, getString(R.string.on_create));
    Utils.printStatus(mStatusView, mStatusAllView);

    TextView DisplayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count_id);
    count ++;

    DisplayText.setText(count);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mStatusTracker.setStatus(mActivityName, getString(R.string.on_resume));
    Utils.printStatus(mStatusView, mStatusAllView);
}
```

The last line **"DisplayText.setText(count);"** crashes the app 
Would really appreciate if anyone helps me on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because count is an int, and setText only accepts strings.

Try this:

```
DisplayText.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

Comment: Only accepts strings? Are you reading the documentation? It accepts `R.string` resources, which are ints... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int).

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, it accepts R.string resources, but those are references to charsequences. For what he wanted to do I think it's sufficient to say that it accepts strings for his usecase. But you're right, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd suggest you to not start variable names with capital letter: `displayText` instead of `DisplayText`.

Second thing is, you don't need to do:

```
count++;
DisplayText.setText(count);
```

Whole point of `++` is to make the code shorter. Simply use `DisplayText.setText(++count)`.

Number three: `onCreate` method will get called only when your activity is first created. And your `count` variable will disappear when your activity is destroyed. So your counter will always show `1`.

And finally about your question, I'm a little bit late since @Zino already answered. When you send an integer to TextView.setText() method, it thinks that it's a string resource id and tries to find it between resources, as mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

You need to convert your integer value to string before sending it to setText method. Here are your options:

```
DisplayText.setText(Integer.toString(++count));
```

or

```
DisplayText.setText(String.valueOf(++count));
```

or

```
DisplayText.setText("" + ++count);
```

Answer (score 0):

setText has more than one overload

```
// This takes a string id (R.string.hello).
// displayText.setText(R.string.hello);
setText (int resid)

// This takes a string in code.
// displayText.setText("Hello");
setText (CharSequence text)
```

You are now using the first one because your are passing a String id and this will fire an Exception because the string resource id is not found.

You need this

```
displayText.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```